# Java script validation issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, grails

I have a bug that I could not figure out in my validation method. I have a function that validate the "code" table in my database to make sure the user can not input duplicate data. It is all working as expected and here is the code:

```
    function validateCode() {
        $('#code-error').html('')

        if ($('#code').val() != '') {


            $.ajax({
                url: '${createLink(action:'checkCode')}',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    'code': $('#code').val(),
                },
                // dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data == 'true') {

                        $('#code-error').html('Code already exist')
                        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

                    } else {
                        // $('#code-error').html('Code not exist')
                        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);

                    }


                },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

But it is not stable.First the message and the button are disabled in the first couples of tried  but if I continue to test it by re-enter the code that exist and the code that does not exist the button disabled however the error message is not showing under the input box.
Here is my html code :

```
        <div class = "row" style = "margin-top:15px;">
                                        <div class = "col-md-12">
                                            <div class = "row">
                                                <div class = "col-md-5 text-right" style = "font-weight: bold"><span class="placeholder">Code</span></div>
                                                <div class = "col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input style = "width: 50%"type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="validateCode()" id="code" placeholder="Enter code" name="code">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="current-code" id = "current-code">
                                                        <div class = "row">
                                                            <div id = "code-error" class = "col-md-12" style ="color:red"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

And here is my controller function for validating the code:

```
   def checkCode() {
        def allow


        String compareCode = params?.code

        def customer = Customer.findByCode(compareCode)

        if (customer == null) {
            allow = false //not exist


        } else if (customer != null) {
            allow = true //exist


        }
        render allow


    }
```